# Using malloc and calloc to create a step structure

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>


int  main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int i = 0;
int n;
int **matrix;

printf("%s","enter the value of n ie number of levels:" );
scanf("%d",&n);
matrix =(int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));

while(i<n)
{
matrix[i]= (int*)calloc((i+1),sizeof(int));
i++;
}


for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{   
    for (int j = 0; j <n; ++j)
    {
        if (matrix[i][j]==0)
        {
        printf("%d  ",matrix[i][j] );
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c ",'B' );
        }

    }
    printf("\n");
}


//printf("%p\n",(matrix[1]));




free(matrix);



return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am trying to create a stair step like structure in using dynamic memory allocation.I purposely used calloc(seeing how zeroes look) so i can check if the array structure I want to create looks like what I want but for various inputs of n i only seem to get a normal 2d array only not like what i have described.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. Also, how do you "get a normal 2D array"? There are no 2D arrays in your code. (But probably there should be.)

Comment: sorry by 2d array i meant that i had a **pointer which i am using like a array

Comment: @userXXX That's not a 2D array. Apart from that, seeing NPE's answer, you probably meant `j < i` instead of `j < n` in the inner `for` loop.

Comment: I purposely wanted to see 0 and garbage values to be sure of the structure I want is achieved or not

Comment: @userXXX You can't do that -- by that, you are relying on undefined behavior, which is nonsensical by definition.

Comment: Than suggest a way by which I can do so

Comment: use2688772: note that garbage values can contain anything, including being all zeros. It's slightly better to use a specific random value if you want to do a smoke test, even that is still not foolproof though.

Comment: How to i do it for random value using memset?Tried that and had the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Your code that allocates the structure is fine and does exactly what you want.

The code that looks for zeros is not fine. Since it reads past the allocated memory it results in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In other words, you cannot check whether a particular address has been `calloc()`ed by reading it and comparing the result to zero.

Once you fix the undefined behaviour, you'll be left with a memory leak: you need to `free()` each element of `matrix` before `free()`ing `matrix` itself.

Comment: Then how do I check that I created structure the way I want.Here was a simple case but in a different case what i can do to check?

Comment: Any other way by which I can do it in C itself?Possibly an alternative to the way I am doing

Answer (score 0):

You have allocated memory for a stair like pattern successfully, but while traversing, you are not following that.

Instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{   
    for (int j = 0; j <n; ++j)
    {
    ...
```

you have to do

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{   
    for (int j = 0; j <i+1; ++j)
    {
```

If you go beyond `i+1` in the inner loop, you may get a `segmentation fault` as you have not allocated memory for that.